# How do single photons travel from here to there

Tags: particle-physics, photons, frequency

I know there have been similar questions but I'm still unclear what the overall consensus is.
(1) I assumed and have read that photons travel in straight lines unless deflected by gravity but there are conflicting theories.
(2) I have heard that single photons takes every possible path but that makes no sense. Why would a single photon traveling from here to the moon go to every other place in the universe along the way. 
(3) I can understand a single photon traveling as a particle or packet of energy but I have a hard time understanding a single photon traveling as a wave. I have never understood any attempts to answer this. 
(4) Does a single photon have a frequency and what causes the frequency? If not then how does it have energy?
I have many questions about single photons and their frequency.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38227/discussion-on-question-by-bill-alsept-how-do-single-photons-travel-from-here-to).

Comment: Ofcourse photon goes on a straight path from one point to other, as much straight as gravity allow. Thats all there is to it. Saying it takes all possible paths is pure nonsense. This is how: its not supported by evidence. Its a story told to justify bad maths. Instead of correcting maths that dont explain data fake data is assumed. Obviously it all conveniently "collapse" to where non nonsense maths says it should be whenever an observation is made. Observation itself has to be magical to justify wrong paths. Has any photon ever observed going any path other than "straight"?

Answer (score 4):

I think CuriousOne's comment provides most of the answers to your question, but for completeness I'll expand it into an answer.

Light is described by quantum field theory and can only be fully understood in this context. We sometimes talk about photons and sometimes talk about light rays, but these are only approximations. As a general principle light behaves like a particle when energy is being exchanged with something else, and like a wave when energy is propagating. So light travels like a wave and interacts like a particle.

Taking your questions in turn:

1. When we look at light propagating in the classical limit then it travels in straight lines (though these straight lines may appear curved in a curved spacetime).
2. When we look at light in the quantum regime then the whole concept of a trajectory is meaningless because the trajectory is a classical limit. At quantum scales no particle, including light, has a perfectly defined trajectory. This is why an electron can go through both slits in the Young's slits experiment - because it doesn't have a single perfectly defined trajectory. The calculation of the classical trajectory can be done in various ways, and the Feynmann sum over paths is one approach. This calculation assumes that light simultaneously travels over all possible paths. To what extent this is just a calculational device and to what extent it reflects an underlying physical reality is a matter of opinion.
3. (and 4) these don't have answers because the questions are based on a misunderstanding of what light is. If you attempted to describe a propagating light ray as photons you would have to use some description like a coherent superposition of many photons.

While it is not the same as a photon, we could think about a light pulse i.e. a short section of a light wave. This is also called a [wave packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet). Wave packets have an average frequency, but they contain a spread of frequencies so a wave packet does not have a single perfectly defined frequency.

Comment: anne v, and CuriousOne  Thanks for your replies but I still have a hard time with it. I realize this is the overall and overwhelming consensus  of the scientific community. But is there not even  room to question that. You have to admit a lot of it goes around and around in circles. It sometimes resembles what it may have been like at the end of the Ptolemaic system when the theories became more and more complex in attempts to maintain what I'm sure the most intelligent and certainly the most educated scientist truly believed in. What is wrong with a single and oscillating photon

Comment: what is wrong with the idea of some description like a coherent superposition of many photons? Have you read my idea on my link at the top of my page?  Or whats wrong with the idea as Anna put it "a progress of a photon"? I understand the reason for probabilities and wave functions but their not real. Whats wrong with getting back to the reasoning of actual things and causalities etc? I truly am not trying to be argumentative, just very interested. Thanks

Comment: @BillAlsept: There is nothing wrong with you religiously believing in the phlogiston, either, it's just not what we call "mainstream physics". You were asking a question of how a modern physicist explains the "motion of photons" and you got the proper answers that solve all the problems you wanted solved. What is not real about a probability, especially since it describes exactly what is being observed? If you don't believe it, buy yourself a cheap photomultiplier tube and do a few experiments with "photons".

Comment: @CuriousOne that my point, no disrespect but to me your ideas to me seem to go in circles. For instance when you talk about using a photomultiplier I'm not sure what to expect? My understanding is that a single photon or small amount of individual photons (physically impact a charged plate which then knock off more photons toward another plate etc. etc. The way you describe it I'm not sure how that would work? Your say no photon travels from A to B, Your saying there some wave that can't be described traveling over there and I guess delivering the photons and there may be other processes.

Comment: @BillAlsept: There is but one quantum field in the entire universe. At low energies, certainly below 1TeV, that quantum field has a remarkably rich low energy structure, some of which is "light" and some of which is "matter". When some of the light part of it interacts with some of the matter part of it, we get the photoelectric effect. That interaction produces discrete events with a certain statistic. Absolutely nothing "pointy" has to "propagate" in this picture. That is exactly what we can observe, the rest of your "photon story" is conjecture based on faulty logic.

Comment: @BillAlsept: physicists are generally arch pragamists and the brutal reality is that quantum field theory works. Indeed quantum electrodynamics is [the most precisely experimentally tested theory there has ever been](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_tests_of_QED). It is tempting to reject theories on the grounds that they are unintuitive, but the lesson of 20th century physics is that intuition is a very poor guide when it comes to physics.

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm not saying the calculation of QM don't work. My calculator can come up with the right answers sometimes but it doesn't explain whats really physically happening. I am just interested in the physical cause of things. People always claim its just the way it is and if we don't understand it then to bad that's just the way it is. Well I will never except that and I hope other don't either.

Comment: @BillAlsept: that is of course entirely up to you, but it's a course that lead Einstein to spend the latter decades of his life as an irrelevance to modern physics. You will at least be in good company.

Answer (score 0):

Mainstream physics has described the microcosm of molecules, atoms, elementary particles with the theory of quantum mechanics, and in particular the quantum mechanical [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of elementary particles, and it has a [mathematical form, a Lagrangian.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model_%28mathematical_formulation%29) . In this Lagrangian the elementary particles, including the photon, are entered as point particles with the mass and quantum numbers shown [in the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg).

The word "wave" comes in quantum mechanical solutions from the first quantization level. The potential problems at first quantization level are solutions of quantum mechanical equations (Schrodinger, Dirac, Klein-Gordon) where interactions are represented by potentials. These equations are called wave equations because their solutions are sinusoidal functions, and sines and cosines are what describe waves in the macroscopic world, from water waves to sound waves and even to classical electromangetic waves.

The innovation in Quantum Mechanics is that the solutions of these equations are not to be considered trajectory solutions, but are to be complex conjugate squared and the value interpreted as a *probability* for a particle to be at (x,y,z) at time t. It is an axiom that has been very successful in describing molecules and atoms  cf [atomic orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) . In elementary particle interactions the solutions  had to be estimated by expansions in pertubative series because of the complexity . This led to the development of the mathematics of second quantization where the solutions for the free  QM equations (no potential), the wave functions , are used to build what is called [second quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization) and quantum field theory, various mathematical formats.

The photon in this framework has its own quantum mechanical equations and its own wavefunction solution. This is a complex wave function and carries the electromagnetic potential information A in complex phases. [It can be shown](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) that a classical electromagnetic wave obeying Maxwell's equation emergenes from a confluence of photons with energy h*nu, and nu is the frequency of the macroscopic wave.

So how does the photon move from A to B? It moves with energy=h*nu and velocity c, and carries information about putative electric and magnetic fields of a macroscopic light beam. In first quantization one says that its *probability* of being at (x,y,z) is the square of the [free photon wavefunction](http://www.cft.edu.pl/~birula/publ/CQO7.pdf) which probability  does vary with frequency nu.

Photons are usually treated with second quantization, which mathematically assumes that the vacuum is composed by the fields of the elementary particles at a ground state, and creation operator manifests the elementary particle at that point in time.

> I have heard that single photons takes every possible path but that makes no sense

You are confusing mathematics with reality, a common enough mistake, (particularly with the concept of virtual particles, but that is another story). The mathematics of calculating the progress of a photon can be formulated in a least action type integral. It does not mean that the photon takes all those paths, as in classical mechanics formulated with the least action, the object does not take all those paths.

Comment: Creation operators don't create particles but quantum states. A path integral has to be evaluated over all paths to produce the correct result, but it doesn't have to be interpreted as a physical mechanism. Indeed, it should be pretty obvious why that is a bad idea. Quantum fields are not Santa and his sled visiting all chimneys in one night.

Comment: @CuriousOne What do you mean with "Creation operators don't create particles"? It certainly changes the expectation value of particle number of a state at least.

Comment: @MikaelKuisma: What state a creation operator creates is a matter of mathematical choice. There is no physical content in the structural existence of creation operators. One can not derive the existence of objectifiable "particles" from such a formal tool. Anna, like many other people in hep, has a very old style outlook on these things that stems from a naive understanding of what can be seen in track detectors like bubble chambers. They mistake what they see for objective reality, no matter how little self-consistent sense it makes when one looks at all the evidence.

Comment: @CuriousOne I agree, what one should not mix formal theory with interpretation. Particle is more like a concept than a well defined thing anyway. It is used quite freely to describe all kinds of resonances of all kinds of fields. If there is a any perceivable peak in any spectrum, somebody is going to call it a particle :) But regardless, I will still continue to use the concept of a particle in connection with creation operators. (Also, I come from solid state, so I do not know much about QFT. There might be some use of concepts, which do not match perfectly)

Comment: @MikaelKuisma: A "particle" is an extremely well defined concept. It is the approximation of the dynamics of an extended body by the dynamics of its center of mass. A "particle" is NOT an object, not even in classical mechanics, it's an approximation procedure that spares us the pain of having to start with continuum mechanics instead of Newton. In QM this procedure stops working completely, which, unfortunately, hasn't stopped plenty of people from making technically 100% false statements about "particles". Particles don't work in solid state physics, either... but OK, if you must.

Comment: @CuriousOne If you have more strict definition of the word 'particle', should you therefore interpret most statements about 'particle' false because your definition differs from the definition used in context? I quote wikipedia "The term is rather general in meaning, and is refined as needed by various scientific fields." The most general definition of a (quasi)particle I can think of is 'a resonance of a propagator'. For example, photoemission experiment measures holes (=quasiparticles), which are the poles of single-particle Greens function. Plasmons are poles of polarization propagator etc.

Comment: @MikaelKuisma: This is not "my definition", it's THE definition that is being used in physics textbooks like Landau-Lifshitz. If a Wikipedia article about physics is written by people with insufficient physics knowledge, that's a valid reason not to use that particular article as a source or to man up and help them make it better, but a bad article on the interweb doesn't redefine basic scientific terms. None of the examples you give are "particles".

Comment: They are quasiparticles at least. Then it is quite common to drop the quasi in normal jargon. I will do so from here on. http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.81.2312 Just as an example this article. One creates quasielectrons (=particles), quasiholes (=particles) and renormalized them with Coulomb coupling to get, for example, bound excitons (=particles) or plasmons (=particles). But it is of course pointless to proceed this 'argument', because this is just about the definition of a word. Also, the site is already complaining about extended discussions in comments:)

Comment: @MikaelKuisma: And none of your "quasi-particles" behave even remotely like "particles". If that doesn't do it for you, nothing I can say will.

Comment: @CuriousOne Except, that they do. For example holes and electrons behave like free ones except for mass: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_%28solid-state_physics%29 ..and excitons diffuse like particles: http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2014/140416/ncomms4646/full/ncomms4646.html In QFT, I am not an expert, but doesn't one renormalize the electrons (due to electron-photon interaction) to match the observed values and one still call them particles? How does the renormalization of these electrons again via Coulomb coupling (electron-photon interaction) suddenly make them 'not particles'?

Comment: @MikaelKuisma Do not get discouraged to expand your understanding of physics by arguments of the type  "mathematical models create reality". Most physicists explore what they consider existing reality using mathematical models, appropriate for the problem under consideration. The concept of "particle" is useful for some contexts, and it is useful in the context of the question above which considers a single photon going from A to B.